# How to access c# visual studio project from different location

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I moved my visual studio project (Visual STudio 2010 > Projects > Project file)  file to a different location (desktop). Then I tried to access the project but when I go to the form file, nothing loads except the form in visual studio. No design view, and I can't even compile it.

How can I open the application like I normally did when it was in its original location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you move it back and then copy the whole folder it is in (project folder) to the desktop? Your other options are to edit the project file itself and change the paths to the project files or copy everything from the original folder to your desktop. I would go with my first recommendation.